# возможно ли. Слушатель на scroll страницы без визуального scroll-а(полоса прокрутки отсутствует) нужен слушатель именно на движение колеса мыши

Tags: javascript, reactjs

это работает если визуально есть scroll(полоса прокрутки присутствует) в моем же случии полосы прокрутки нету

мне надо задиспатчить событие при движении колеса мыши

```
document.addEventListener('scroll',e => {
    console.log(`scroll`)
})
```

Comment: Вам нужно событие [wheel / mousewheel](https://learn.javascript.ru/mousewheel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй .addEventListener('wheel',)